# Passing Command to Function in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I am creating a setup bash script so I can quickly setup my servers.

Inside the run function I want to pass the command, which the run function will then verify whether is successful.

```
function run () {
    if output=$( $1 ); 
        then printf 'OK. («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
        else printf 'Failed! («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
    fi
}

printf 'Setting up «uni» as system group...'

run " if [ ! $( getent group uni ) ]; 
          then sudo addgroup --system uni; 
          else echo 'Group exists.'; 
      fi "
```

However this results in a error: `setup.sh: line 5: if: command not found`

When I do this it works fine, but I want to eliminate repetitive code as I ha ve many commands:

```
if output=$(
    if [ ! $( getent group uni ) ]; then sudo addgroup --system uni; else echo 'Group exists.'; fi
); 
    then printf 'OK. («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
    else printf 'Failed! («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside re: `function myfunc() {`, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (the `function` keyword is referenced in both 1st and 3rd tables).

Comment: ...more on-point for the question, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): _I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!_

Comment: Basically, though: The shell's expansion ordering prevents data from being unintentionally treated as code (the root of all shell injection vulnerabilities) when expansion happens in the defined waterfall order (in which all security-sensitive syntax parsing happens _before_ values are expanded). When you start parsing from the top, as `eval` and `sh -c '...'` do, then all the potentially-unsafe steps can happen; so anyone reading your code needs to audit whether there's potential for untrusted data to be expanded before that restart takes place. As such, it makes your code harder to review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *safe* way to pass code to functions is... to encapsulate that code in another function.

```
run() {
  local output
  if output=$("$@"); then 
    printf 'OK. («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
  else
    printf 'Failed! («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
  fi
}

printf 'Setting up «uni» as system group...'

step1() {
  if [ ! "$(getent group uni)" ]; then 
    sudo addgroup --system uni; 
  else
    echo 'Group exists.'; 
  fi
}

run step1
```

If your code didn't involve flow control operators (and otherwise fit into the definition of a "simple command"), you wouldn't even need to do that; with the above `run` definition (using `"$@"` instead of `$1`),

```
run sudo addgroup --system uni
```

...would work correctly as-is.

---

Using either `eval` or `sh -c` exposes you to serious security problems; see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for a high-level overview, and see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a discussion of why code shouldn't be passed around as text (and preferred ways to avoid the need to do so in the first place!)

Comment: Wouldn't `output=$("$@" 2>&1)` be better to capture error in `$output`?

Comment: @anubhava, I agree, but I'm not trying to define behavior for the OP -- the only bugs I fixed in their preexisting code are ones I was confident they were unaware of. Similarly, if I were writing this myself I would pass any nonzero exit status through to the caller, but since they didn't try, I assume it's behavior they don't want.

Comment: I was editing my answer with pretty much the same idea ^^
But I think to works, you need to add an exit with something different than 0 in the else part of your step1

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen to pass a shell command string to your function (aka `system(3)` semantics). This means that you have to use `eval` to evaluate it:

```sh
function run () {
    if output=$( eval "$1" ); 
        then printf 'OK. («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
        else printf 'Failed! («%s»)\n' "$output"; 
    fi
}
```

Note that the parameter with your command will be expanded as normal, so if you want the `$(getent)` to be evaluated in the `run` function instead of before it, you will need to escape it:

```sh
run " if [ ! \$( getent group uni ) ]; 
          then sudo addgroup --system uni; 
          else echo 'Group exists.'; 
      fi "
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a bash piece of code as a function args to be evaluated in a subshell and test the success, you can do it like that:

```sh
#!/bin/bash 

run () {
  # Here I'm not sure what you want to test, so I assume that you want to test if the piece of bash pass as an arg is failing or not
  # Do not forget to quote the value in order to take all the string
  # You can also try with "eval" instead of "bash -c"
  if output=$( bash -c "${1}" ); then 
    echo "OK. («${output}»)"
  else 
    echo "Failed! («${output}»)" 
  fi
}

# Do not forget to escape the $ here to be evaluated after in the `run` function
# Do not forget to exit with a code different of 0 to indicate there is a failure for the test in the "run" function
run "if [[ ! \$( getent group uni ) ]]; then sudo addgroup --system uni else echo 'Group exists.'; exit 1; fi"
```

**Warning:** I posted this piece of code to make your script works the way you seems to want (have a function which will eval your code from a string and interpret the result) but it's not safe at all for [this reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) as [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) pointed out in the comment section.

It's probably safer to make something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

run () {
  if output=$("${@}"); then 
    echo "OK. («${output}»)"
  else 
    echo "Failed! («${output}»)" 
  fi
}

one_of_your_functions_you_want_to_eval() {
  if [[ ! $( getent group uni ) ]]; then 
    sudo addgroup --system uni 
  else 
    echo 'Group exists.'
    # do not forget to exit with something different than 0 here
    exit 1
  fi
}

run one_of_your_functions_you_want_to_eval
```

Note: in order to declare a function, either you declare it like that (POSIX compliant syntax):

```sh
your_function() {
}
```

Either using a bash only syntax (I think it's better to avoid "bashism" when it not bring real values to your scripts):

```sh
function your_function {
}
```

But no need to mix both syntaxes ;)

Comment: This _works_, but it's an extremely bad idea; has all the vulnerabilities described in [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) even though it doesn't use `eval`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I know but that's the purpose of his function which leads to an evil use of eval (or whatever that will eval the code from a string). So I focused on explained why it doesn't work and what to do to make it work that way, but not what he should do instead. I'll update my answer to add a warning.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure that the explicit use of `$?` is an improvement over the original code -- it's not only extra verbosity, but it makes it easy for someone to add a logging command or some other statement after the assignment and unintentionally modify `$?` before the conditional takes place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I also agree on that and will update my answer again

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's done, I also suggest another safer solution that doesn't not implies to eval a stringify piece of bash